# Blender and facial mocap

Tags: python, scripting, motion-capture

I have decided to post this question because I don't know what else can I do. I've been following a tutorial about facial mocap using OpenCV and webcam with Blender 2.8. This is the tutorial I'm talking about:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7nNO3FLkLU

There are a number of differences between the tutorial and what I'm doing but all comes down to the tutorial running on Linux while I'm using windows 10.

I've been following the tutorial along but nothing seems to work! The version of Blender I'm working with is using a stand alone version of python and that's been a nightmare! Installing dlib was almost impossible! I tried with CMake and then dlib but didn't work! So, I had to load a normal installation of python 3.7.4 to match Blender 2.81 internal python 3.7.4 installation. At that point I thought that it was pretty much done! I ran:

```
python.exe -m ensurepip

python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip --user

python.exe -m pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python imutils numpy dlib --user
```

And everything was fine after that!

The next step was running the scripts and that's where I am right now! I got an error message that said:

```
module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'
```

I tried updating dlib and didn't work. I assume that, if the library was not installed, I would have an ImportError instead.
I tried to re-install dlib (`pip uninstall dlib`, `pip install dlib`) but didn't work!

So, not sure what other thing can I do! If anybody can help me I'll greatly appreciate! I know I'm not the only one having these problems! Hopefully this post become the answer to other people as well!

Comment: Two things I'd recommend, as much as I'd like to put the second first.  Set up a python virtual environment using the python of your blender installation Install all the 3rd party modules there. At any time if you rename the python folder in blender to say `_python` You can start blender and use the venv python.  And secondly:  think about  installing a linux flavour (I'd recommend Ubuntu) on your PC... i

Comment: Recommend asking questions re installing 3rd party python modules on stackoverflow.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912372/dlib-installation-on-windows-10

Comment: Hey batFINGER! Merry christmas and thank you very much for your help! The first thing I did was creating a bootable USB with Linux! I tried Ubuntu first and didn't work! I also tried Manjaro and ran pretty much in the same problems! I spent two weeks trying everything I could think of and I couldn't make it work! I ended up banging my head with Linux! It was so frustrating! The tutorial make it look so easy...and yet I'm having so many problems!

Comment: To make things even worse, I created a model in blender for windows and tried to open it in blender for Linux and I couldn't! That was enough for me and decided to try windows.
My target is to have it all up and running before the end of the year. At this point doesn't look like I'm gonna make it….
Even people who, somehow, manage to make it run in windows are having problems with it. They are reporting that is very very slow and not very responsive! but according to them it looks like a blender related problem...

Comment: At this point I'm not sure about what to do! Shall I try Linux and make it run smooth!? or shall I keep trying on windows!? If I go with Linux I'll have to do the character I already did from scratch. If I go with windows I'll have the character but the mocap won't be as smooth as it should!
To be honest at this point I'm considering paying someone to make a Linux bootable usb for me and installing blender and everything I need for the mocap (including scripts, etc. In other words, someone who can deliver everything ready to use) so that I just have to take care of the character!